# Show DIV only when iframe page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe page within a DIV and I only want the DIV to display once the iframe page is loaded/available. If the iframe page does not load/not available, do not show that DIV at all.

I wrote some JS however it doesn't work as I expected it to, the DIV still display regardless if the iframe page is available or not.

Code:

```
<div class="ad-container" style="display:none">
   <iframe src="//oonagi.org" border="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
</div>

var adContainer = $('.ad-container');
// check if ad container exist
if(adContainer.length > 0) {
  // only show ad once iframe page is loaded
  adContainer.find('iframe').load(function() {
    adContainer.css('display', 'block');
  });
}
```

Comment: The iframe is still loaded even if the page is available or not. You would need to have a control inside the iframe to notify the parent window.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no authority over the iframed page. Is there no other solution?

Comment: One work around is to create an ajax request to the url and update the div display if the return was success. But this is not a good solution because two requests will be made to the third party website.

Answer (score 0):

you should change iframe src at `document.ready` inorder to make it fire your iframe load's event.you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#frame').bind('load', function() { //binds the event
        $('#ad-container').show();
    });

    var newSrc = $('#frame').attr('src') + '?c=' + Math.random(); //force new URL
    $('#frame').attr('src', newSrc); //changing the src triggers the load event

});
```